# Can an SCSS list of variables inherit?

Tags: css, sass, sass-variables

I have some lists of SCSS variables which are used in mixins, can I create a 'master' list which the others inherit?

```
$vars: (
  main-colour-active: #0b8579,
  text: #424242,
  button-text: $white,
  font-family: $font-family-base,
);
```

```
$nav: (
  inherit $vars,
  background-color: $blue,
);
```

expected outcome

```
$nav: (
  main-colour-active: #0b8579,
  text: #424242,
  button-text: $white,
  font-family: $font-family-base,
  background-color: $blue,
);
```

I have looked into scss inheritance, I know I could add those $vars to a variable within my $nav but would prefer them to all be in one list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map.merge()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps#add-to-a-map):

```scss
@use 'sass:map';

$nav-new: map.merge($vars, $nav);
```

Or:

```scss
$nav: map.merge(
    $vars,
    (
        // ...
    )
);
```

Try it:

```scss
@use 'sass:map';

$vars: (
  text: #424242
);

$nav: (
  text: #fff
);

$nav-new: map.merge($vars, $nav);

#foo {
    color: map.get($nav-new, text);
}
```

...compiles to:

```css
#foo {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [map-merge](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps#add-to-a-map) also you can get the index number of a map

```
$colors1: (
   primary:      red,
   secondary:    blue,
   accent:       #ddd,
);

$colors2: (
   black:        #000,
   white:        #fff
);


// you can use it like this =>

$colorsGenerated1: map-merge($colors1, $colors2);

@each $key, $value in $colorsGenerated1{
  $i: index($colorsGenerated1, $key $value);
  
  .test1 {
      margin: #{$i}rem;
      background-color: $value;
  }
}


// also you can use it like this =>

$colorsGenerated2: map-merge($colorsGenerated1, (
   pink:        pink,
   purble:        purble
));

@each $key, $value in $colorsGenerated1{
  $i: index($colorsGenerated2, $key $value);
      
   .test2 {
       margin: #{$i}rem;
       background-color: $value;
   }
}
```